# get the date for xarray rolling min or max

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

Calling `foo.rolling(time=100).mean()` will give the mean for a rolling period of 100 days.
I would like to find the minimum and maximum values within this 100 day period. Easy with `foo.rolling(time=100).min()`

However, how can I find the exact day of this minimum and maximum? I want to know what dates the min and max periods are during this rolling 100 day window. Or will I need to write my own function to do this?

```
num=4000
data = np.random.rand(num, 3)
locs = ['one', 'two', 'three']
times = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=num)
foo = xr.DataArray(data, coords=[times, locs], dims=['time', 'space'])

foo.rolling(time=100).max()
foo.rolling(time=100).min()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use [`DataArrayRolling.construct`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.core.rolling.DataArrayRolling.construct.html) to explicitly create windowed views of the `foo` and `time` DataArrays.  E.g. in the case of `argmin`:

```py
windowed_foo = foo.rolling(time=100).construct("window_dim")
windowed_times = foo.time.rolling(time=100).construct("window_dim")
indexes = windowed_foo.argmin("window_dim")
result = windowed_times.isel(window_dim=indexes)
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you use `argmin` with `rolling(...).reduce`, then use those values to select dates from the rolling window.